# How to disable a range of dates depends on the work hours?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to close a range of hours cells so that the user can't book on that specific hour, i've created a modal windows that allows the admin to set his own working hours every day all the week.

**Update**:

I've found a solution, i have to add this little magic to my fullcalendar 
**businessHours** where it can take any list of hours, but the problem is how to disable the event click on the non-business hour ?

here is my new **code**:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth',
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    businessHours: 
    [
        {
            dow: [0], // Sunday
            start: '08:00',
            end: '13:00'
        },
        {
            dow: [1], // Monday
            start: '09:00',
            end: '12:00'
        }, {
            dow: [2], // Tuseday
            start: '13:00',
            end: '15:00'
        }, {
            dow: [3], // Wedensday
            start: '15:00',
            end: '17:00'
        }, {
            dow: [4], // Thursday
            start: '12:00',
            end: '19:00'
        }, {
            dow: [5], // Friday
            start: '10:00',
            end: '15:00'
        }, {
            dow: [6], // Saturday
            start: '11:00',
            end: '20:00'
        }
    ],
    select: function(mydate, start, end, event, jsEvent, allDay, businessHours, view, element) {

        var DaysOK = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
        var mydateObj = new Date(mydate);
        var chosenDay = mydateObj.getUTCDay();

        if( // Clicked event hour in business hours ){
            alert('You can book!);
        } else {
            alert('You can\'nt book');
        }
    }
```

And why `console.log(businessHours)` inside console gives **undefined** ??

Please any help or suggestions would be tons appreciated .

Comment: Any answer guys !!

Comment: " how to disable the event click on the non-business hour ?". Just to be clear, you want to disable clicking on _existing events_ during non-business hours? That's what your wording says, but it kinda seems unlikely. Did you mean you don't want the user to be able to create new events during non business-hours? In that case just set this option https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/ to "businessHours" as described in that documentation.

Comment: P.S. Your definition of the `select()` callback is nonsense. See here    https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/ for what parameters fullCalendar passes to it. You can't just add whatever parameters you feel like to it and expect them to be there when the function runs later on. fullCalendar has to call that function later in its code. There's no way for it to know what extra parameters you wanted passing in, and it might not even be possible. P.P.S.`console.log(businessHours)` is undefined because businessHours is a property of fullCalendar, not a global variable)

Comment: @ADyson, yes i don't want any user to create any event if it not in working hours , now i understand what you mean about property i didn't noticed that sorry :)

Comment: I can make that possible by sending `ajax` request to the server with event data and in the back-end it will compare them with data inside the databse since i am saving the data after they get created on the calendar , but for me it doesn't make much more sense since it could be done within the calendar !!!

Comment: Well, your server should always double-check what the client sends it, because client-side restrictions are trivial for a malicious user to bypass, but yeah you don't need to use that test directly in the UI - like I said in my first comment, above, have you tried setting the `selectConstraint` option? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/

Comment: @ADyson, yes i tried it worked perfectly, thanks dude for your help :)