# Why fullcalendar moving my event 30 minutes automatically on click?

Tags: fullcalendar

If i want to create event on the calendar, the event moving automatically step forward i don't know why and its adding 30 minutes to the original time, for example if i clicked on **13:00** i get inside `consloe` **13:30**, i don't know why.

Also i've created an `<input>` field to set the start time into it so i can see which datetime i've choosed , and again i get a plus 30 miuntes datetime !!!!

Here is my **code**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initialLocaleCode = 'ru';
    var d = new Date();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },

        timezone: 'local',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 650,
        locale: initialLocaleCode,
        navLinks: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: false,
        resizable: true,
        eventResize: true,
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "22:00:00",
        eventLimit: 6,
        unselectAuto: false,
        selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
        businessHours: 
        [
            {% for work in current_user.work_hours %}
            {
                dow: [{{work.day_number}}],
                start: '{{work.work_start.strftime("%H:%M")}}',
                end: '{{work.work_end.strftime("%H:%M")}}',
            },
            {% endfor %}
        ],

        select: function(mydate, start, end, event, jsEvent, allDay, view, element) {

            var DaysOK = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
            var mydateObj = new Date(mydate);
            var chosenDay = mydateObj.getUTCDay();

            var modal = $('#modal_calendar');
            var title = $("select#serviceTitleCalendar option").filter(":selected").val();

            if (title) {

            $(modal).attr('style', 'display: block; top: 53px; left: 404px;');
            $('body').append('<div id="mwb" onclick="MWHide()"></div>');

            $("select#serviceTitleCalendar option").filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() == $("#serviceSet").val();
            }).attr('selected', true);

            $('#book-calendar').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));

            $("select#serviceTitleCalendar").off("change");
            $('#send-appo').off("click");

            $("select#serviceTitleCalendar").on("change", function() {

                var nameService = $(this).val();
                var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                $('.loading').html('<div class="spinner"> <img id="ld_spinner" src="/static/img/icon/circle-slack.gif" alt="spinner"/></div>');
                if ($(this).val() == 'Выберите услугу') {
                $('#dynamic-period').text('минутами');
                $('.loading').html('<div class="spinner" style="display: none;"></div>');
                return false;
                } else {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    url: '{{url_for("panel_abonent.get_service_period")}}',
                    data: {
                        service_period: nameService
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $('.loading').html('<div class="spinner" style="display: none;"></div>');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        if (data.time_period){
                        $('input[name="period"]').val(data.time_period);
                        $('#dynamic-period').text(data.time_period.split(':')[1]+' минут');
                        } else {
                        return false;
                        }
                    }
                    })
                }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the `select` callback is incorrect.

You gave:

```
select: function(mydate, start, end, event, jsEvent, allDay, view, element) {
```

But the fullCalendar docs (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) show the parameters which fullCalendar will supply to that function when it runs it. It shows the following:

```
function( start, end, jsEvent, view, [ resource ] )
```

(where resource is optional depending whether you have got the Scheduler plugin).

As you can see, the documentation has an example where the first parameter in the list is called "start" , and the second is "end". You can call them what you like, of course, but it's intended to indicate what those parameters contain.

However, in your code, you've called the first parameter "myDate", and called the second one "start". This doesn't mean that the second parameter actually *is* the start. It's just a name you decided to use.

Also, you've defined too many parameters, more than fullCalendar will send values for. Mapping your parameters to the values fullCalendar has supplied to it will give you:

- mydate: Start date/time of the selection
- start: End date/time of the selection
- end: JavaScript event with information such as mouse coordinates
- event: the current View
- jsEvent: a resource (but only if you use Scheduler. Otherwise, no value)
- view: (no value)
- element: (no value)

So when you write

```
$('#book-calendar').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

the variable you called "start" actually contains the end time. The default duration of a slot is 30 minutes, so that's why that value is 30 minutes later that the time you clicked on.

You need to make your definition of the "select" callback match the documentation, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

To clarify the concept: when you define a callback like this, you're giving fullCalendar a function to run at a later time. You can specify whatever parameter *names* you like, but you can't just add extra parameters - how will fullCalendar know what you intended, or what values to supply for it? In the fullCalendar code, there is already fixed code which will call the function you gave it, and will send it the parameters it decides to. That number of parameters, and what kind of info they contain, is decided when the programmer wrote the code. Only the *values* of the parameters are decided at runtime, not the quantity or the types. You have no control over any of that.

Comment: thanks man always the saver, i didn't noticed that i need to fill in the `select` parameters in the right way , now everything is working ;)

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Actually I recognised your username and was looking through your question history just now, and noticed I mentioned this same thing to you already in the comments on this one a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241352/how-to-disable-a-range-of-dates-depends-on-the-work-hours

Comment: Actually i forgot about it , that question was a little different where i have had to use the `selectConstraint` selection, also i did the same mistake but again i didn't noticed it ;)